# How can I do mathematical operations to two columns of a CSV file and save the result in a new CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file (such as *test1.csv*). There are tabular values like the following.

```
S1     S2     S3
4.6    3.2    2.1
3.2    4.3    5.4
1.4    3.4    6.1
```

I want to do mathematical operations, such as `R1=(S1+S2)/1.5` and `R2=(S2+S3)/2.5`. Then I want to save the results `R1` and `R2` in a new CSV file (such as *test2.csv*). I tried with the following code. That does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
df2['R1'] = (df['S1'] + df['S2'])/1.5
df2['R2'] = (df['S2'] + df['S3'])/2.5
df2.to_csv('test2.csv')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not define `df2` before attempting to use it.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({})
df2['R1'] = (df['S1'] + df['S2'])/1.5
df2['R2'] = (df['S2'] + df['S3'])/2.5
df2.to_csv('test2.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can an array to a dataframe and divide a dataframe by a list of values.

```py
df2 = (df[['S1','S2']]
       .add(df[['S2','S3']].values)
       .div([1.5, 2.5])
       .set_axis(['R1', 'R2'], axis=1)
      )
df2.to_csv('test2.csv')
```

Comment: This code would be more readable if it were split into multiple lines.

Comment: Yup, that is much better for reading.